# Нужно ли выделить запятыми уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, нужно ли выделить запятыми уточнение ***в дюнах***?

*Недалеко от всего этого в дюнах живет пастух-туарег с женой и дочкой.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: *Недалеко от всего этого, **в дюнах,** живет пастух-туарег с женой и дочкой.*

Здесь обособление **задает структура предложения**, так как сочетание "недалеко от всего этого в дюнах" сложно прочитать в одну фразу.

С токи зрения **семантики**  второе обстоятельство места можно считать **уточняющим или пояснительным** по отношению к первому (он обозначает дополнительную информацию).

Answer (score -1):

Артём, при желании можно и выделить. А в случае отсутствия такого желания можно и не выделять))

> В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство. Ср.: *Впереди на дороге толпились люди* (т. е. в передней части дороги). — *Впереди, на дороге, толпились люди* (т. е. сама дорога находилась впереди); *Далеко в лесу раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится в лесу). — *Далеко, в лесу, раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится вне леса).
>
> http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118

Таким образом, в определении своего желания рулит то, находится ли «всё это» в оных дюнах или располагается отдельно. А если это неизвестно, тогда не знаю, что и посоветовать))

Comment: Возможно, заминусовавший товарищ просто не любит меня. Или Розенталя))

Comment: Что касается друзей, то они у меня есть и без, в группе поддержки я не нуждаюсь. В непрошенных советах тем более. И я уже не слишком рад, что вернулся.